# quilljs replace <strong> with <b>

Tags: reactjs, meteor, quill

I have a Meteor React app.

I'm using Quill, but **bold** produces a `<strong>` tag instead of a `<b>` tag.

To render the HTML through dangerouslySetInnerHTML it doesn't display `<strong>` as bold.

Is there a way to have Quilljs use `<b>` instead of `<strong>`?

Comment: `<b>` is the uncool "presentational" tag, whereas `<strong>` is the supposedly more "semantic" tag, which separates the intent from the appearance. It's up to you how you choose to style _strong_ content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just add a css class to make `<strong>` bold?

```
strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that was easy :)

Comment: This is just a dirty workaround which work for web maybe, but doesn't fix things when the resulting text is to be used in iOS or Android

Comment: Still stores in the DB as <strong>, taking up 10 more bytes per tag pair.

Answer (score 10):

I took the info available here: https://quilljs.com/guides/how-to-customize-quill/#customizing-blots and extended it to include italic also.

Using Quill in chrome (not using Meteor React at this point), using the HTML extracted using quill.root.innerHTML, the use of  `<strong>` and `<em>` did not bold or italic the text.

The following code is run after the quill library is loaded and solves my version of this issue:

```js
// set Quill to use <b> and <i>, not <strong> and <em>

var bold = Quill.import('formats/bold');
bold.tagName = 'b';   // Quill uses <strong> by default
Quill.register(bold, true);

var italic = Quill.import('formats/italic');
italic.tagName = 'i';   // Quill uses <em> by default
Quill.register(italic, true);
```